# HOCON : How to limit the base include

Tags: typesafe, typesafe-config, hocon

I am using a HOCON configuration file where I am having a base file like

```
Value{
  key1{
    somekey: testvalue
  }
  key2{
    somekey: testvalue
  }
}
```

There are 2 derived confs which are like below
Conf1

```
include "base"
value{
  key3{}
}
```

Conf2

```
include "base"
value{
  key4{}
}
```

I need the result like Conf1 should contains **"Key1" and "Key3"** where as Conf2 should contain **"Key1","Key2" and "Key4"**. Can I achieve this using hocon base config?

Comment: On what base `key2` should be omitted in Conf1 ?

Comment: I can specify into conf that what key I want to use